# Adobe Flex form losses focus so default button doesn't work

Tags: apache-flex, focus

I have a form that looks like the following:

```
<mx:HBox width="100%" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">
        <mx:Panel horizontalAlign="center"
                  title="{resourceManager.getString('Resources','views.login.title')}"
                  verticalAlign="middle">
            <mx:Form id="loginForm" defaultButton="{loginButton}">
                <mx:FormItem label="{resourceManager.getString('Resources','views.login.ip')}">
                    <mx:Label id="url" text="{url}"/>
                </mx:FormItem>
                <mx:FormItem label="{resourceManager.getString('Resources','views.login.username')}"
                             required="true">
                    <mx:TextInput id="username"/>
                </mx:FormItem>
                <mx:FormItem label="{resourceManager.getString('Resources','views.login.password')}"
                             required="true">
                    <mx:TextInput id="password" displayAsPassword="true"/>
                </mx:FormItem>
            </mx:Form>
            <mx:FormItem  direction="horizontal" width="100%" horizontalAlign="right" paddingBottom="2" paddingRight="2">
                <mx:Button id="loginButton"
                           label="{resourceManager.getString('Resources','views.login.loginBtn')}"/>
            </mx:FormItem>
        </mx:Panel>
    </mx:HBox>
```

The behavior I experince some times (not always) is when I tab from username to password and then try to hit "Enter" the Botton's click callback does not get called. If I click on the label (id is "url") then go into any of the textboxes, "Enter" key works just fine. I am assuming that the form somehow keep loosing focus. I would appreciate any idea about solving this problem.

Comment: Usually to get a form to submit when a user presses the enter key, I listen for keyUp events on the input boxes.  That solution could work here too.

Comment: That could be a potential solution, but what is wrong with using defaultButton? Isn't that the preferred way at least in theory?

Comment: I'm not sure what the preferred way is.  In many cases; I have found the mx:Form to not support the layouts my customers request, so only use it for quick and dirty POCs.  I'm not sure about the Spark form which should be more flexible.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, although, since wen the login is incorrect and I hit enter on the Alert box - it propagates to the login box and get into this vicious circle. I need to figure out how to spot the bubbling of that event. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand why hitting enter on an Alert box would propogate to a login box.  Do you have a sample of that?

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue recently, did you find the root cause? I found a workaround is set the form `defaultButton` in `creationComplete` handler instead of on the `mxml` tag. I saw this issue in Flex4.1, I don't see it in Flex 3.6. I haven't try flex 4.6 though.

Comment: I can confirm this ... I set the defaultButton in MXML of a BorderContainer and it didn't work, but setting it in the ceationComplete handler did the job :-) Thanks for that pointer